# Error converting uuid4 value to string in Pydantic model

Tags: python, string, fastapi, uuid, pydantic

I'm new to Python and Fastapi. The problem is Fastapi response body schema shows me this error everytime I attempt to make a post request. Firstly, I intend to convert uuid4 into string using the hex function then display the converted output in the response body.
What I want is that the field named api_key automatically generates dynamic default uuids for each input record (not the same as id but rather a field to store unique values)

```
**
422 Unprocessable Entity

{
  "detail": [
    {
      "loc": [
        "body"
      ],
      "msg": "'str' object is not callable",
      "type": "type_error"
    }
  ]
}**
```

And here is the code I tried:

```
class Terminal(BaseModel):
    api_key: str = Field(title="api key", default_factory=uuid.uuid4().hex)
    name: str = Field(..., title="Terminal name", regex="[^\s]+")
    mac: MACAddressStr = Field(..., title="MAC address")
    mgmt_ip: IPv4Address = Field(..., title="Management IP")
```

All the fields that require user input works perfectly fine.
It also works when I tried to enter api_key as a string manually.
My desired output:

```
{
  "api_key": "5876753e02f141b5a83f7e9cff6db1ba"  // auto-generated
  "name": "terminal1",
  "mac": "aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff",
  "mgmt_ip": "1.1.1.1"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.field)

> default_factory: If provided, it must be a zero-argument callable that will be called when a default value is needed for this field. Among other purposes, this can be used to specify fields with mutable default values, as discussed below. It is an error to specify both default and default_factory.

So, doing this is going to work:

```
default_factory=lambda: uuid.uuid4().hex
```